# contextmenu not working for live content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I am using [contextmunu right click script](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdContextMenu/sample.htm) . This is working for elements which are static loaded on pages. But for dynamic content like after click on 'Add category' 'contextmenu' function is not working.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

           $("#add_category").click(function(){
                     $("#category_list").prepend('<h4 style="color: #53B332;" class="new_category" >New Category</h4>');
                     return false;
           });


            var option = { width: 150, items: [
                            { text: "Item One", icon: "sample-css/wi0126-16.gif", alias: "1-dsds1", action: menuAction },
                            { text: "Item Two", icon: "sample-css/ac0036-16.gif", alias: "1-2", action: menuAction },
                            { text: "Item Three", icon: "sample-css/ei0021-16.gif", alias: "1-3", action: menuAction },
                            { type: "splitLine" },

                            ], onShow: applyrule,
                onContextMenu: BeforeContextMenu
            };
            function menuAction() {
                alert(this.data.alias);
            }
            function applyrule(menu) {               
                if (this.id == "target2") {
                    menu.applyrule({ name: "target2",
                        disable: true,
                        items: ["1-2", "2-3", "2-4", "1-6"]
                    });
                }
                else {
                    menu.applyrule({ name: "all",
                        disable: true,
                        items: []
                    });
                }
            }
            function BeforeContextMenu() {
                return this.id != "target3";
            }


            $(".new_category").contextmenu(option);


});
</script>
 <a href="#" id="add_category">Add category</a>
 <div id="category_list" class="panel-body">
                  <h4 style="color: #53B332;" id="target" class="new_category">New Category</h4>
 </div>
```